# How to ignore a field from DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have a list of persons in DB everyone having a CV field which is a MultiPart File in Spring. I'm trying to get all persons from db, but to ignore the CV field because I don't want to be downloaded when I use getAllPerson function. It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to ignore a field when serializing to JSON you could use `@JsonIgnore` tag.

If you want to inlcude it on the Json but not on the Jpa use `@Transient` and `@JsonInclude` tags.

If you just want to not read and specific field from the database every time you get an element then you could use [Lazy loading](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading) on that field. Then, only when you use the getters for that field you will retrieve it from the DB.

Finally, if you want different serializations on JSON you can use [JSON Views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation). This will allow you to define diferent views of the same object and select the one you want to use when serializing.

All this tools can be used in concordance to achieve whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can.
you have to create a new interface with get methods for your specified fields like below.

```java
interface Person{
    String getId();
    String getName();
}
```

and then create a method for your repository to get the data list by mentioning your new `Person` object  like below.

```java
List<Person> findAllWithoutCV();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
**@JsonIgnore** annotation directly on the field: